# Confusing with an URL parsing regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I met a url parsing regular expression in a proxy [PAC file](https://github.com/goagent/goagent/blob/2.0/local/proxy.pac).

Its function is to match any url pattern belongs to the domain wikimapia.(btw, just my guess)

```
^[\w\-]+:\/+(?!\/)(?:[^\/]+\.)?wikimapia\.org
```

I split it and give my confusion as following:

```
^ 
[\w\-]+     // any protocol name containing '-' ?
:
\/+         // why not use '\/\/', aren't protocol names follow by '://' ?
(?!\/)      // what's the function of this part?
(?:[^\/]+\.)? // is non-capturing grouping ?: necessary here? or just for optimization?
wikimapia
\.
org
```

Hope someone can explain my confusion.

Comment: `[\w\-]+` need not mandatorily contain a `-`

Comment: This expr appears to be broken, for example, it matches `http://google.com?blah=foo.wikimapia.org`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [rfc](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) a URL can contain `-` in the schema (protocol) and for non IP based protocols you can have more than two `/`'s. For `http` however it should always be `://`.

The `(?!\/)` (negative lookahead) asserts that whatever comes after "the" string of `/`'s is not a `/`. This however does not serve much purpose, most regex engines are greedy, so it would consume all the `/` it can, so there shouldn't be any non `/` characters left. Furthermore, the next character is either not `/` in the optional `(?:[^\/]+\.)?` portion, and if that is not matched then the next character would be `w` in `wikimapia.org`. So ultimately the lookahead serves no purpose.

Unless you are actually referencing capture-groups, making any group non-capturing has no impact on anything but performance. I would say it is still a good thing to do though, having that habit makes it easier if you are actually using back-references.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `(?!\/)` is a negative lookahead assertion. In other words, assert that the character following this assertion, is not a forward slash. I can't understand why it's being used. As you state in your question, a couple of forward slashes would surely suffice:

`[\w\-]+:\/\/(?:[^\/]+\.)?wikimapia\.org`

Answer (score 0):

I can't say much about that expression itself, but this would be better:

```
var suffix = 'wikimapia.org';
if ((matches = url.match(/^(([^:\/?#]+):)?(\/\/([^\/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?/)) {
    if (matches[4] && matches[4].substr(-suffix.length) == suffix) {
        // valid
    }
}
```